# React - How to exclude specific array value in includes function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array

```
export const INVALID_CODES = [
  'code_1659',
  'code_5430',
  'code_7482',
  'not_valid',
];
```

And to render message I used `includes` function

```
const renderMessage = (): boolean => {
  return !INVALID_CODES.includes(apiResponse.invalidCode);
};
```

My problem is I want to exclude 'code_5430' in `renderMessage` to be used in other conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you think of exclude, you should almost always use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const renderMessage = (): boolean => {
    return !INVALID_CODES
      .filter(x => x !== "code_5430")
      .includes(apiResponse.invalidCode);
};
```

Comment: This approach is better and more scalable. Use this approach instead.

Answer (score 2):

My way to overcome this problem is to put the `code_5430` as the first element (`[0]`) in the array, and check the include from the second element.

Like:

```
export const INVALID_CODES = [
      'code_5430',
      'code_1659',
      'code_7482',
      'not_valid',
 ];

const renderMessage = (): boolean => {
    return !INVALID_CODES.includes(apiResponse.invalidCode, 1);
};
```